# How to modularize the output of a kable function?

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I would like to create a module to knit tables to pdf for different levels of a variable. The final output should be one distinct table for each of the values specified.

For example, from the dataset `iris`, the variable `Species` has values `c("setosa", "versicolor", "virginica"`

I can produce a table for setosa using the code below:

```
    library(knitr)
    library(dplyr)
    g <- 'setosa'
    iris %>% filter(Species==g) %>% 
summarise(avg=mean(Sepal.Width)) %>% 
kable(caption=paste('Results for',g))
```

But I would like to make it more efficient by passing a vector of values to print the output by (namely setosa, versicolor and virginica).
I know in this case I could just group by Species, but my original code has more extensive output and I would rather print it into different tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a function and loop through the vector:

```
library(purrr)
print_kable <- function(species) {
        iris %>% filter(Species == species) %>% 
            summarise(avg=mean(Sepal.Width)) %>% 
            kable(caption=paste('Results for', species)) %>% 
            print()
        }

walk(.x = c("setosa", "versicolor", "virginica"), print_kable)
```

**Edit**

For a markdown document, the code chunk should look like this:

````
```{r results='asis'}
library(dplyr)
library(knitr)
library(purrr)
print_kable <- function(species) {
        iris %>% filter(Species == species) %>% 
            summarise(avg=mean(Sepal.Width)) %>% 
            kable(caption=paste('Results for', species)) %>% print()
}
walk(c("setosa", "versicolor", "virginica"), print_kable)
```
````

Comment: Thanks, I get `Error in filter(., Species=species): object 'Species' not found`

Comment: I forgot to mention: the only shows up only when I knit (to pdf)

Comment: Hmm, it worked when I generated the PDF. Which version of dplyr are you using?

Comment: 5.0...I also tried to clean the session just in case. When I run it in the console it works, but it doesn't knit. Btw, why is the `print()` needed?

Comment: My apologies, I wasn't loading the library dplyr after cleaning the console, so it runs...but the output of the tables has those console-style dashed-lines rather than the pdf layout for tables that kable usually renders.

Comment: Did you add results='asis' to the chunk options?

Comment: Ok so one of the missing parts was the `asis`. But a second issue is that it would not actually work unless I assign `ff <- lapply(c("setosa", "versicolor", "virginica"), print_kable)`. If you edit the answer accordignly I am ready to accept, thanks.

Comment: That's weird, I tried it in two computers and it worked fine. Using `lapply` defeats the purpose of avoiding any return values (that's why I used `walk`). Anyways, I'm glad you could make it work on your side!

Comment: I am not sure why but `walk` return a 4th empty table with just column name `avg`